# Objective-C: Extract Text From a URL

Tags: iphone, objective-c, url, text, web

I am wondering how i would go out onto the web and grab a body of text from a specific website, then display it to a user within my app.  I got the whole display part, it is the grabbing text from a URL that has me stumped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [TFHpple](https://github.com/topfunky/hpple), a XPath Parser which allows you to parse HTML and other DOM documents

Answer (score 0):

You want stringWithContentsOfURL.

Comment: That was deprecated, use stringWithContentsOfURL:encoding:error: instead.